# Storing facebook information efficiently in a database for future queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, facebook

I am creating a website that has the option for users to login via facebook, and when a user logs in, my database would store his/her information obtained from facebook.

The SQL code that created the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE facebook_users (
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    username varchar(255),
    firstname varchar(255),
    lastname varchar(255),
    email varchar(255), 
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)
```

an example of one row of the information provided by facebook would be:

```
user_id:    241123463541244
username:   John Smith
firstname:  John
lastname:   Smith
email:      johnsmith1977@gmail.com
```

Every time a user logs in, my website would check if a row already exists with that user_id, and if it didn't would create it and insert the appropriate informaiton:

```
$user_id = 241123463541244;//obtained from facebook via the access_token

$sqlStatement = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE user_id = ".$user_id.")";
$sqlStatementPrepared = $conn->prepare($sqlStatement);
$sqlStatementPrepared->execute();

$row = $sqlStatementPrepared->fetch();

if ($row === false)
{
    //code that inserts a new row into the facebook_users table     
}
```

My concern is that the current user_id would cause speed issues for future queries when the database grows to over 1 million rows (or 10 million, etc), especially considering that the rows would be created one after the other when a new facebook user logs in for the first time, which means that the user_id values are not in an increasing or decreasing order.

**QUESTIONS:** Will the current MySQL format cause speed issues for future queries when the database grows to over 1 million rows? If so, is there a better method I could use to increase performance?

Comment: There shouldn't be any speed issues if the table is indexed for your future queries.

Comment: @TabAlleman By setting the PRIMARY KEY to user_id during the creation of the table, would that mean the table is indexed appropriately or does indexing need some other configurations? I am relatively new to databases and MySQL hahah. I am using a database provided by godaddy's web hosting service that uses Apache on a linux server.

Comment: What indexes you should create depend on what queries you intend to run in the future.   How to index tables is a big topic that is too broad to cover in a Stack Overflow question.  There are lots of articles about it already freely available on the internet.

Comment: @TabAlleman K, thanks dude, your answers were very informative.

Comment: You start looking into what might happen when your app gets 1 million users perhaps around the time you reached a tenth of that.